# Lerna bootstrap does not link local dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg, lerna

What is the proper way of working with lerna and local dependencies?

---

I have configured two modules in a mono repo to use lerna with a local dependency. I expected that

```sh
$ lerna bootstrap
$ lerna run test
```

would be sufficient to download all external dependencies, link a local dependency and execute and pass all tests in all modules.

### Expected Behavior

As per the [lerna bootstrap](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/bootstrap#usage) documentation:

> 2. Symlink together all Lerna packages that are dependencies of each other.

Thus, I expected that `lerna bootstrap` would create a symlink in `module-b/node_modules` below that points to `module-a` (which then would allow the tests to be executed and pass).

### Current Behavior

No linking occurs, which cause the tests to fail:

> lerna ERR! yarn run test exited 1 in 'module-b'
>   lerna ERR! yarn run test stdout:
>   yarn run v1.19.1
>   $ jest
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
>
> lerna ERR! yarn run test stderr:
>   FAIL ./import.test.js
>     ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> Cannot find module 'module-a' from 'import.test.js'
>
> > 1 | const moduleA = require('module-a');
>     | ^
>   2 | 
>   3 | test('should import module-a', () => {
>   4 |   moduleA();
>
>   at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (import.test.js:1:1)
> ```

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Create the folder structure below
2. Copy the files inlined to their corresponding directory
3. Execute `$ lerna bootstrap` followed by `$ lerna run test`

```
project-root
   + packages
   |       + module-a
   |       |      + package.json
   |       |      + index.js
   |       |
   |       + module-b
   |       |      + package.json
   |       |      + import.test.js
   |
   +  lerna.json
```

*packages/module-a/package.json*

```
{
  "name": "module-a",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Test passed in module-a\""
  }
}
```

*packages/module-a/index.js*

```js
module.exports = () => console.log('Log in module-a');
```

*packages/module-b/package.json*

```
{
  "name": "module-b",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "module-a": "file:../module-a"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^24.9.0"
  }
}
```

*packages/module-b/import.test.js*

```js
const moduleA = require('module-a');

test('should import module-a', () => {
  moduleA();
});
```

*lerna.json*

```
{
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "independent"
}
```

### Observation

Executing [lerna link --force-local](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/link#--force-local) does not change status quo, the test still fails because the `module-b/node_modules/` still does not contain a reference to `module-a`.

### Remark

I cannot use [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) together with lerna because `module-b` is an Electron app and the electron builder expects its dependencies to be installed in the `packages/module-b/node_modules/` folder.

### Environment

- lerna --version 3.18.4
- npm --version 6.11.3
- yarn --version 1.19.1
- node --version v12.12.0
- macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 7):

I have tried your implementation.

Using `file:../module-a` in `packages/module-b/package.json` does not work for me.

You can go around it easily by using writing a version number for `module-a` (it does not matter which since we will `force-local`)

```
{
  "name": "module-b",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "module-a": "1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^24.9.0"
  }
}
```

At the root of your project:

Bootstrap and link for local version:

`npx lerna bootstrap --force-local`

Run tests:

`npx lerna run test`

Comment: Another work-around is to manually "hoist" your intra-package dependencies by adding them to the root package.json per [lerna issue #2352](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2352#issuecomment-753682568). Ideally [PR #2789](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/pull/2789) will fix this.

Answer (score -2):

for me its worked, and installed packages in node_module folder

```
npx lerna exec -- npm install
```

Comment: I don't believe this is a valid solution. 
this executes an `npm install` on every packages in the repo, which takes forever, and doesn't need to be done. 

`lerna bootstrap` is supposed to link to packages that are already installed. 

the issue is that sometimes it doesn't link dependencies of dependencies... 

a `lerna link` at the end of my bootstrap command seems to be fixing it...but i'm checking still...